# Django - Rendering new form fields based on selected choices

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to render new form fields based on the selected form choices?

Consider this model and form:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(models_extra.Client, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    task = models.ForeignKey(models_extra.TaskType, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    description = models.ForeignKey(models_extra.Description, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

```
class TaskSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
```

How can i make it so the form renders new fields for every specific task?

Assume that i have an extra model (i don't and i'm not sure that the solution is about this):

```
class ExtraInfo(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(models.Task, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    field = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

Example: In this new model i have 3 entries for task nr 1 -> (task1, 'Airport') (task1, 'Order nr') (task1, 'Subject')

How can i make it for my template to render the new fields "Airport", "Order nr" and "Subject" when the task with id = 1 is selected?

Is there any better way to make a form of this kind?

edit. I've already made this question today but i'm simplyfing it in order to get some ideas.